# Android ActivityRecognition not working in htc oneX

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I am developing an android app which makes use of Google play service activity recognition for detecting driving. While testing my app with HTC 1X, my application was getting call backs for activity recognition. Later I uninstalled and re installed my application. But after that, my application was not getting any  call back from Google play services related activity recognition. When I installed another application which makes use of Google play service, that application was able to get callbacks related to activity recognition in the same device.

I tried uninstalling and re installing my application. But even after that my application was not getting any callback from Google play services. Finally when I forced stopped Google play service and cleared the app data of Google play service, my application started to receive callbacks from Google play services.

Do you guys have any idea why my application was not getting call backs related to activity recognition from Google play services after uninstalling and reinstalling my application. while other applications were getting the call back in the same device and my application started getting call back only after force closing the Google play services and clearing the data.

Note: I was able to reproduce this issue only once. But our testing team had reported this issue earlier. So there is a good chance that this issue can come up again.

Comment: If another app can use ActivityRecognition and yours can't, having everything else constant, it means that your app has some problems. Not familiar myself, but have debugged that way and found my problem here. I suppose people'd ask some code, so you can add that eventually.

Comment: I got the issue only single time ,the same code working in all devices.i cannot reproduce it again.

Comment: I hope you can reproduce it, since I have no clue how you can find a solution to something you cannot reproduce. Good luck, and I hope it was something with Google, not with your app!

Answer (score 2):

I too had this kind of an issue.Did you get any solution for such scenarios?.Sometimes for no reason the play services stops responding.
I found two particular conditions where this happens

- If the network Provider is disabled .
- If the allow mock locations is enabled.(Not sure if this itself is the reason)

Correct me if am wrong ,add to this if you have any inputs